# how to add data to table row from the dropdown selected in a dialog box

Tags: sapui5

I have the dropdown in dialog as:

```
    if (!this.pressDialog) {
        this.pressDialog = new Dialog({
  title: "Wafer",
  contentWidth: "40px",
            contentHeight: "300px",
            content: [
    new sap.m.Text({width:'100%', text: 'Component Name' }),

    new sap.m.Select({
    width: '60%', 
    items: [

    new sap.ui.core.Item("item11", {text: "Disregarded"}),

    new sap.ui.core.Item("item12", {text: "Corporation"}),

    new sap.ui.core.Item("item13", {text: "Partnership"})

    ]

    }),

    new sap.m.Text({ width:'100%',text: 'Category' }),
    new sap.m.Select({
      width: '60%',
      items: [

      new sap.ui.core.Item("item1111", {text: "Disregarded"}),

      new sap.ui.core.Item("item1234", {text: "Corporation"}),

      new sap.ui.core.Item("item1314", {text: "Partnership"})

      ]

      }),


          new sap.m.Text({width:'100%', text: 'Quantity' }),
          new sap.m.Select({
            width: '60%',
            items: [

            new sap.ui.core.Item("item15211", {text: "Disregarded"}),

            new sap.ui.core.Item("item136454", {text: "Corporation"}),

            new sap.ui.core.Item("item213754", {text: "Partnership"})

            ]

            }),

        new sap.m.Text({width:'100%', text: 'MainCategory' }),
        new sap.m.Select({
          width: '60%',
          items: [

          new sap.ui.core.Item("item11411", {text: "Disregarded"}),

          new sap.ui.core.Item("item34", {text: "Corporation"}),

          new sap.ui.core.Item("item314", {text: "Partnership"})

          ]

          })],




            beginButton: new Button({
                type: ButtonType.Emphasized,
                text: "OK",
                press: function () {
                    this.pressDialog.close();
                }.bind(this)
            }),
            endButton: new Button({
                text: "Close",
                press: function () {
                    this.pressDialog.close();
                }.bind(this)
            })
        });

        //to get access to the global model
        this.getView().addDependent(this.pressDialog);
    }
```

It looks as:

[image]

How can I capture the data here from the dialog box and add to the table having the columns as same as each item,

- Component Name,
- Category,
- Quantity,
- main category

I am trying how can I make a JSON from the values of selected dropdown so that can bind to the table

Sorry for one more Q: `how can I center the select boxes` in a dialog

Any help or guiding links are appreciated TIA!

[image: table is as]

Comment: Please, it's important in Stack Overflow to focus on one precise question (see help how to ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I understand is that you want to make a Json model from the selected  dropdown (`sap.m.Select`). We first create the model :

```
let model= {
            "componentName": "Disregarded",
            "category": "Disregarded",
            "quantity": "Disregarded",
            "mainCategory": "Disregarded",
        };
let jsonModel = new JSONModel(model);
this.getView().setModel(jsonSetting, "tableModel");
```

Than for each `sap.m.Select` we have something like this (example for category):

```
new sap.m.Select({
                        width: '60%',
                        textAlign: "Center",
                        selectedKey: "{tableModel>/category}",
                        items: [
                 new sap.ui.core.Item("item1111", {text: "Disregarded",key:"Disregarded"}),

                 new sap.ui.core.Item("item1234", {text: "Corporation",key:"Corporation"}),

                 new sap.ui.core.Item("item1314", {text: "Partnership",key:"Partnership"})
                        ]
                    }),
```

You have to add key for each `sap.ui.core.Item` like the desirable text and than to specify dynamic binding between the model and selected item `selectedKey: "{tableModel>/category}"`. When another item is selected the change will be visible in the model.

To center the text in the select boxes use `textAlign: "Center"` and if you want to center against the dialog use `sap.m.FlexBox`:

```
new sap.m.FlexBox({
         justifyContent: "Center",
         items:[
              new sap.m.Select({
                    ...
              }),
         ]
}
),
```

If the select boxes appear wrapped delete property `width:60%`

Now you have the model ready and you can bind it with the table (I think you want this in the function of OK button ).

Note that the variable `model` will specify the initial selected keys for each `sap.m.Select` (everyone set to Disregarded).

Comment: Exactly , I'm looking for the same....Thanks mate. I would refer this and ask you back for doubts

Comment: May I know how could I use `sap.m.FlexBox` for the same ... How can I put select inside a flexbox if i'm not wrong....I want to have the whole select box to align center to dialogue

Comment: Thanks a ton mate, it worked as a magic!! if you have some free time could you please look at this Q   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60166309/how-to-update-the-rows-of-a-table-using-dialog-box