# How to update the rows of a table using dialog box

Tags: sapui5

I have been going through the below Plunker,

[plunker link here](http://embed.plnkr.co/fbiPgiJTILHiAXv48R3b/)

Here If I try to edit , the new record is added above instead of updating the current ,

How can I update the current edited row for the same example instead adding a new one?

- I have tried deleting the row and update the new in the deleted place , but this idea is not correct tmk

Any guiding links or any help is much appreciated ....TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace an item in an array with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915789/how-to-replace-an-item-in-an-array-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

From your code I understand you want to update the model (variable `aData`). It would be a better idea to use data binding but if you want to edit it you can use:

```
aData.map(function(item) { 
if (item.ID==id){
    item.Name = name;
    item.Age = age;
    item.Salary = sal;
}
return item; });
```

This is probably not the efficient way to do it and it consider you have unique ids.
Also don't use the function `unshift()` because it add new value (doesn't update the existent).The record is added above because you actually add a new element (see [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)).

Comment: sure mate , I understood , Thanks for all the explaination and the link

Comment: Hey @S. Florin could you please help me with this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426558/how-to-add-the-rows-at-last-and-perform-drag-and-drop-accordingly-for-the-demo-s

Answer (score 0):

You should try to work with data binding rather than manually extracting and inserting your values:

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.33/docs/guide/91f0ca956f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

Nevertheless, if you do want to edit a property of an item in your array, you can edit it as follows:

```
array[index].property = "new value";
```