# How to add the rows at last and perform drag and drop accordingly for the demo sample from documentation

Tags: sapui5

[Here is the link for the sample from DOCS for Drag and Drop](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.DnD/code/Controller.controller.js)

For adding the rows down to each other from table1 to table2 I have changed(line 149 in controller `Before to After`)

```
moveToTable2: function() {
    this.getSelectedRowContext("table1", function(oSelectedRowContext) {
        var oTable2 = this.byId("table2");
        var oFirstRowContext = oTable2.getContextByIndex(0);

        // insert always as a first row
        var iNewRank = this.config.defaultRank;
        if (oFirstRowContext) {
            iNewRank =  this.config.rankAlgorithm.After(oFirstRowContext.getProperty("Rank"));
        }
// Here in the above line 

        this.oProductsModel.setProperty("Rank", iNewRank, oSelectedRowContext);
        this.oProductsModel.refresh(true);

        // select the inserted row
        oTable2.setSelectedIndex(0);
    });
},
```

On performing this the rows get added down to each other , but drag and drop of rows doesn't work,

I understood that the rank algorithm changes accordingly but How does the rank affect here while drag and dropping the rows ?

I couldn't find other such examples to look more in to this ,

Any explaination or any guiding links on this is really appreciated and would be much helpful, TIA

Comment: With this method `moveToTable2`, are you sure that  the rows are always added last? I think you need to use the context of the last row  not `oFirstRowContext` (index 0), and modify the rank according to last row rank. Also, the methods responsible for drag and drop, `onDropTable2` and `moveSelectedRow` work the same as before modification ?

Comment: As a trial and error , i have just put `After` for `Before` in `moveToTable2` .....But I am sure rows are added at last and yes it's obvious that methods responsible for drag and drop didn't work.....

Comment: Hey @S.Florin Could You help me on this Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775228/how-to-add-the-data-to-table-rows-in-xml-view